# TCP Packets are sometimes combined (and delayed?)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcp

I am sending packets from server to client and vice versa every 500ms to indicate that the connection is still alive. However, sometimes these packets are delayed and mutliple packets are combined together. The problem is that this would cause a "connection timeout" when it might simply be a delay.

A 10 second delay of packet sending seems quite long to me on any modern Internet connection. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

On both server and client messages are sent and received like the following example where the final received packet consists of several packets combined. This happens on both server and client simultaneously.

```
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
SENT ALIVE PACKET
RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE
PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE
PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE
PACKET RECEIVED ALIVE PACKET ****RECEIVED TIMEOUT PACKET****

Connection Timeout.
```

**Edit**

This has never happened on my other PC running the same code.

**Edit 2**

The combining of packets is not a problem, but packets should be sent directly and not delayed.

Comment: Are you using KEEPALIVE?  Are you setting TCP_NODELAY?  See setsockopt().

Comment: `TCP_NODELAY` makes this happen less frequently, but it still happens. What do you mean by `KEEPALIVE`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packets sometimes get concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049310/packets-sometimes-get-concatenated)

Comment: TCP/IP at the level of `send`/`receive` is a stream not a packet protocol.  So you get a continuous stream of bytes when reading it.  At the lower layers it can merge / split however it feels like and you will read part/multiple "messages" you have sent.  If you have blocks of data you conciser messages you need to implement a messaging format; length prefix is one of the simplest.

Comment: @RichardCritten I understand, but I used TCP to not receive any packets out of order and to be more certain about the delivery of packets

Comment: @Z0q As TCP/IP hides all of the packet details from you, you can't receive "packets".  When you call `receive` it will pass you however much is in it's buffer. This can cause sent messages to be split or joined depending on the transport layer.

Comment: I have an additional question: Does it really make sense to ckeck periodically that a TCP connection is still existing? Such a mechanism is already included in TCP itself.

Comment: @Z0q there is no spoo.. packets at application level, just one or more bytes, (octets), in a stream.

Comment: For delayed packets get Wireshark (or similar) and have a look at the captured trace. Could be as simple as a slightly loose connection.

Comment: @MarcusS Good question. I don't see any need for it. HTTP doesn't do it, and it's the most widely used application protocol on the planet. Sometimes this is done to keep connections alive through routers that would otherwise time them out, but this seems to me to be an abuse: if connections are so precious to the router that it needs to time them out, that's what should be allowed to happen.

Comment: @cdarke What does TCP keepalive have to do with it?

Comment: @EJP:  probably nothing, but the question showed no code to indicate how the packets were being sent.  I have seen keepalives fail in this way.

Comment: @cdarke You've seen keepalives 'fail' by causing packet delays and coalescing? Even though they aren't sen't when there have been recent packets? Are you sure you diagnosed it correctly? And how do you reconcile that with the OP's claim that turning it *on* fixed it?

Comment: @EJP:  I only asked the OP a question, I did not offer a solution and did no diagnostics.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, and I am asking you why you asked the question. Doing so suggests that it has some relevance, and the OP has so interpreted it, and he has now duped himself into thinking that keepalive fixed it, which it certainly didn't, or else if it did it totally contradicts the experience you cited.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the `KEEPALIVE` option to my sockets seemed to have resolved this issue.

Thanks to @cdarke.

Comment: I don't see how. It has exactly zero effect until two hours have elapsed. You must have changed something else.

Comment: @EJP: 2 hours is typically the default, but some systems (like Linux) support `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL`, and `TCP_KEEPCNT` socket options via `setsockopt()` to allow per-socket customizing of the intervals used by `SO_KEEPALIVE`. Windows doesn't have those options, but it does have `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` via `WSAIoctl()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, but there is still nothing in the TCP keepalive mechanism that would cure these delays. I can't imagine why it was even suggested. Surely he has disabled the Nagle algorithm, or fixed something in the hardware.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with my application. Sometimes the error comes back and sometimes adding a printf() could fix the problem and removing it would make it come back. Sometimes certain packets would not be received (about 1 out of 100). I was thinking it might be a memory leak or uninitialized variable?